# robust linear regression with interaction

Tags: regression, r, machine-learning

I am looking how epigenetic age associated with toxic element exposure in four different road buffer zone (1000m, 2000m, 3000m, &4000m) using robust linear regression. I can run robust linear regression without interaction term, but could you please help me how to run robust linear regression with interaction term (Hg*buffer zone). I have tried below to run robust regression with interaction term but I am not getting 1000m buffer zone interaction with Hg and also I am not getting Pvalue. I want to use Age, sex, and smoking status as covariates.

```
   > summary(rr.huber <- rlm(PCGrimAge_IEAA ~ Hg*buffer.zone + Sex +Age+ Smoking_Status, data = ph))

Call: rlm(formula = PCGrimAge_IEAA ~ Hg * buffer.zone + 
            Sex + Age + Smoking_Status, data = ph)
Residuals:
  Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-7.68190 -1.59376 -0.01048  1.58263 16.07211 

Coefficients:
                               Value    Std. Error t value 
(Intercept)                     -0.4037   0.5335    -0.7567
           Hg                   -0.2404   0.3345    -0.7187
buffer.zone2000m                 0.4443   0.6275     0.7081
buffer.zone3000m                 -0.3850   0.3601    -1.0692
buffer.zone4000m                 -0.6141   0.5109    -1.2020
Sex                             -1.9878   0.1239   -16.0398
Age                              0.0011   0.0066     0.1720
Smoking_Status                   2.7252   0.0922    29.5725
Hg:buffer.zone2000m              -0.6463   0.8488    -0.7614
Hg:buffer.zone3000m              0.2163   0.3691     0.5860
Hg:buffer.zone4000m              0.5614   0.5351     1.0491

Residual standard error: 2.352 on 1801 degrees of freedom
(1 observation deleted due to missingness)

> library(emmeans)
> EMM <- emmeans(rr.huber, ~ Hg * buffer.zone)
> EMM  
Hg    buffer.zone  emmean     SE df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
0.876 1000m        0.0311 0.1602 NA    -0.283    0.3452
0.876 2000m       -0.0911 0.2949 NA    -0.669    0.4868
0.876 3000m        -0.1644 0.0774 NA    -0.316   -0.0127
0.876 4000m        -0.0909 0.1572 NA    -0.399    0.2173

Results are averaged over the levels of: Sex 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Some elements are having huge variation between 1st and 3rd quantile or even o value; do you think this datasets need some cleaning before running robust linear regression or regression model can handle this?

```
> summary(x)
      As               Cd                  Al            Ba   
 Min.   : 0.00001   Min.   :0.00001   Min.   :0.00001   Min.   :  0.00  
 1st Qu.: 3.80000   1st Qu.:0.23381   1st Qu.:1.56500   1st Qu.: 83.12  
 Median : 6.20000   Median :0.28333   Median :1.97000   Median :105.00  
 Mean   : 6.37249   Mean   :0.31966   Mean   :2.18731   Mean   :109.46  
 3rd Qu.: 8.12222   3rd Qu.:0.36368   3rd Qu.:2.54100   3rd Qu.:130.33  
 Max.   :35.10000   Max.   :2.46500   Max.   :5.97333   Max.   :446.67
```

Comment: Don't remove the intercept. Learn how to interpret treatment contrast instead. Possibly calculate estimated marginal means with the emmeans package.

Comment: thanks, Roland, could you please suggest correct code and how to use emmeans?

Comment: Your code can be corrected simply by removing `0+`. The [emmeans](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/index.html) package has vignettes that you can study.

Comment: The reference levels of your categorical predictors are encoded by the intercept or the main effects. `Hg` *is* the estimate at `buffer.zone1000m`, the other parameters estimate the *difference* in the other categories. This is how any statistical model works, overparametrizing would otherwise lead to an infinite amount of solutions.

Comment: thank you so much updated code with emmeans; but I am not getting epigenetic clock association in emmeans.

Comment: @Pbulls, so can I understand that intercept is showing association of Hg.1000 buffer zone with epigenetic clock here.

Comment: You are assuming a strictly linear association between `Hg` and  outcome. Check quality control of your model to see if that very strong assumption makes sense. Also, if you have 10 toxic elements as indicated in a comment on an answer, you should _NOT_  do 10 separate regressions. A single model including all will avoid problems with [omitted-variable bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias) and help minimize [multiple comparison problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's run through the model parameters and `emmeans`. Your model itself will predict the mean epigenetic age given a set of predictor variables. I'm not so sure a normal approximation is necessarily best for such outcome, but let's side-step that for now.

For every categorical predictor you will have a reference level (R chooses the first level of a factor by default), and then additional parameters that model the *difference* from that reference level. Any model will work like this because if you were to include a separate parameter for every category the model would be overparametrized, and an infinite number of solutions would exist. The one exception here is the overall intercept that can be replaced by the reference level of any one categorical predictor; this will make all predictors in that variable model the mean in each category rather than a reference & differences. This causes a slight change in interpretation of those parameters but is otherwise equivalent, and only works for one variable.

Otherwise, the reference category for a categorical predictor is absorbed into the overall intercept or into the main effect for an interaction. This means that the `buffer.zone1000m` mean is modeled by `(Intercept)`, and the way the mean changes by `Hg` *for that category* through the `Hg` effect. The other `buffer.zone` parameters model differences in means versus the intercept, and the interactions model differences in means by `Hg` for those categories. The intercept does not only model `buffer.zone1000m` though, it also includes all other references (e.g. for `Sex`) and the zero value for any numerical predictors.

Specifically, this means that a subject having `buffer.zone1000m` and all other predictors at zero (reference sex, smoking status, age and Hg of zero) will have a predicted epigenetic age of $-0.4037$. This usually isn't too meaningful in itself, I consider it very unlikely that there's anyone in your dataset with age zero -- unless you centered this predictor, but it looks like you didn't. For every unit increase of `Hg` such subject is predicted to decrease their epigenetic age by $-0.2404$, so if they had for example `Hg = 10` their predicted epigenetic age would be $-0.4037 + 10\times -0.2404=-2.8077$. Would the very same subject have been in `buffer.zone2000m` instead you would have to account for two additional parameters: the one modelling the difference between these two categories (the `buffer.zone2000m` effect) and its interaction with `Hg`. Their predicted epigenetic age would become, with parameters in order of the printout, $-0.4037 + 10\times -0.2404+0.4443+10\times -0.6463=-8.8264$

The `emmeans` output shows the result of exactly such calculations. You've asked for `buffer.zone` and `Hg` only, so it keeps other covariates constant at some default value. `Hg` is fixed at what is presumably its mean, $0.876$. Calculation of the specific predicted means would require knowledge of the values that sex, age, and smoking status were fixed at (the bottom line suggests that `Sex` was held at $0.5$ or possibly the observed proportion in the data), but we can still recover the differences between the categories: with everything else fixed, going from `buffer.zone1000m` to `buffer.zone2000m` the difference is $0.0311 + 0.0911=0.1222$, which is equal within rounding precision to the parameters of `buffer.zone2000m + 0.876 * Hg:buffer.zone2000m` or $0.4443+0.876\times -0.6463=-0.1218$. In this way you can use the model parameters to predict the epigenetic age of any combination of predictor values. Calculations of standard errors of such estimates are a bit more involved, so that's where the pre-packaged code very much comes in handy.

**Edit**: I realize I missed your request for *P*-values. [This R-help answer](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-July/108659.html) might be informative in that regard (summarizing: with robust regression you cannot rely on the same distributional assumptions as for the standard linear model). You could use the reported means and standard errors to construct Wald-type statistics, with all the (possibly wrong!) assumptions that those entail. `emmeans` has already produced the confidence interval in that way.

Comment: thanks PBulls, do you think for plotting forest plot I should use emmean as Estimate or effect size along with confidence interval that emmeans generated? so can we say that at 1000m road buffer zone Hg exposure associated with epigenetic age acceleration by (0.0311). and at other buffer zone Hg exposure associated with age deceleration. but in emmeans code I haven't mention anything about epigenetic age, it just Hg and road buffer variable along with model. not sure if need to mention other covariates in emmeans code as it say Results are averaged over the levels of: Sex

Comment: @bioinfonext You get the association from the parameter estimates: for 1000m, every unit increase in `Hg` is predicted to reduce the outcome by -0.2404. For the other zones you have to add their interaction effects, so e.g. 2000m is -0.2404 + -0.6463 = -0.8867 per unit increase, for 3000m it's -0.2404 + 0.2163 = -0.0241, and finally 4000m is -0.2404 + 0.5614 = 0.321. Only for the last zone `Hg` seems to *increase* the outcome based on this model. This ignores the fact that the zones may also have different ages (the main zone effects).

Comment: I am basically interested in how Hg toxic element exposure is associated with epigenetic age acceleration (PCGrimAge_IEAA) in different road buffer zone (1000m, 2000,m, 3000m and 4000m) while adjusting for Age, sex, and smoking

Comment: thanks PBulls, such a nice explanation. But is there any R packages that can do these calculation by itself? I need estimates as you have shown above, confidence interval for forest plot? and could we prove significant association based on confidence interval instead of p value?

Comment: I do have 10 toxic element so need to run all regression and at the end I want to plot forest plot for all element how they are associated with epigenetic age acceleration depending on the buffer zone. Here I am thinking to run regression individually one by one for each element separately. that's why I need correct estimate and confidence interval ; it will be bit hard to do calculation as you have shown above for each element. But it help me a lot to understand how basic regression statistic works.

Comment: @bioinfonext I believe you can get your desired contrasts for example via `marginaleffects::avg_comparisons(rr.huber, variables="Hg", by="buffer.zone")`. There's probably a lot of other packages that can produce these results.

Comment: thanks PBulls for your all help and time. Do you think should I use here log2 converted toxic element value?

Comment: And would it be possible to check wether model fitting correctly or not? can I also include other covariates in this model that might also be also associated with epigenetic age acceleration, so that we can correctly estimates toxic element exposure on epigenetic age acceleration.